# Using sed to remove multiple lines

Tags: bash, sed

For the purpose of the project, i can only use sed, not grep, awk or print.

How do i use sed to remove the line start from, let say bbbb or eeee, till the end of the package name.
The end of each package is not unique and random, and the number of the line also random, sometime 9 lines, sometime 4 or 5.

Couldnt get this work. Since the only thing i can control input is the Package name to start, but how do i remove it to the end of that package.

```
            Package: aaaa
            Status: 
            Priority: 
            Section: 
            Installed-Size: 
            Maintainer: 
            Architecture: 
            Version: 
            Depends:
            Description: 
            Name: 
            Icon

            Package: bbbb
            Status: 
            Priority: 
            Section: 
            Installed-Size: 
            Maintainer: 
            Architecture: 
            Version: 
            Depends:
            Description: 
            Name: 
            Homepage: 


            Package: cccc
            Status: 
            Priority: 
            Section: 
            Depends:
            Description: 
            Name: 
            Homepage: 


            Package: dddd
            Status: 
            Priority: 
            Section: 
            Installed-Size: 
            Maintainer: 
            Architecture: 
            Version: 
            Depends:
            Description: 
            Name: 
            Homepage: 


            Package: eeee
            Status: 
            Priority: 
            Section: 
            Installed-Size: 
            Maintainer: 
            Architecture: 
            Version: 




            Package: dddd
            Status: 
            Priority: 
            Section: 
            Installed-Size: 
            Maintainer: 
            Architecture: 
            Text: 




            Package: ffff
            Status: 
            Priority: 
            Section: 
            Installed-Size: 
            Maintainer: 
            Architecture: 
            Version: 
            Depends:
            Description: 
            Name: 
            Link: 



            Package: ggg
            Status: 
            Priority: 
            Section: 
            Installed-Size: 
            Depends:
            Description: 
            Name: 
            Homepage:
```

Comment: Please re-ask your question. It is totally non-understandable what you're trying to accomplish.  Maybe the desired output would help...

Comment: And share what you tried and what you searched on. SO is not a free code service.

Comment: And you answer is already on [this thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/multiline-pattern-match-using-sed-awk-or-grep) You just have to adapt it

Comment: Not doing your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/Package: bbbb/,/^ *$/d' YourFile
```

assuming your `bbbb`is the name of the pacakage (no other occurance seen in sample) and paragraphe end with a empty line (only allowed is space char)

Comment: It worked. Thank you. By the way, its not homework, i have tried other method but not this. So its a new thing for me. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/bbbb/{b=1;next}b==1&&/Package/{b=0}b==0' input.txt
```

removes lines from `bbbb` until it find next `Package` text

Comment: OP said they can't use awk for this 'Project'

Comment: @Jidder, it was tagged for `awk`, it is re-tagged.

Comment: It does say in the first sentence though that they don't want an awk solution. It was obviously mistagged.